# apache poi language version causes date format misinterpretation

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Edit:
To avoid confusions, here's an (again) improved version of my original question:

**QUESTION**
How can I read out the String representation of a cell just the way Microsoft Excel would display it, without knowing respective hard-coding the formatting-settings (but for example using the cell's own formatting settings to format the output).

**ANSWER SO FAR**
This will be no problem if you are using the US-version of excel, for all other versions Apache POI will return strings equivalent to how the US-Version of excel will display it and there is no built-in way in Apache POI to change this. Only way I can confirm is "working" is - as Gagravarr suggested - to switch the language on my Mac to US/EN. Then Apache POI and Excel will deliver the same result. Which is kind of a inverse solution.

The problem is: A cell is displayed like `01.12.13` in the german version of excel, but since it's formatted as a Date

```
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
HSSFDataFormatter formatter=new HSSFDataFormatter();
String val=formatter.formatCellValue(cell)
```

gives me a val of `21/01/13`.

---

the original question was:

I am having a xlsx file containing date fields that are displayed in Excel like

`01.12.13` using the format setting of the cell `TT.MM.JJ`

If I read the same file with apache poi, getting the cell and format à la

```
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
HSSFDataFormatter formatter=new HSSFDataFormatter();
String val=formatter.formatCellValue(cell)
```

(with `cellIter` being a valid Iterator of course, simplified example)

my `val` turns out to be `21/01/13`. As I understand the HSFDataFormatter's method formatCellValue() should return a String of the value formatted with the cell's format setting.

Does anybody know how I can get the val to contain the same format as in Excel?

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: I'm fairly sure your file won't actually have Ts and Js in the format string, I suspect that's the "magic" Excel localisation kicking in. If you open your file on a machine in a US locale, does it show there the same way that POI does?

Comment: Yay! You are totally right when I switch my Mac to English the formatting in Excel is just the same as in Apache POI! For a workaround I just somehow need to know how to read out the format settings of the cell.

Comment: Excel has two kinds of format strings, those which "magically" localise themselves, and those that look the same everywhere. I'd suggest your format your cells explicitly as the latter, firstly so that POI is able to get what you want out, and secondly so anyone else you send the file to sees it the way you do too!

Comment: The problem ist that my client gets those excel sheets by his client and it's not gonna happen that they're gonna format their sheets correctly. For most offices Excel-Formatting is still Voodoo. Just poke it until it looks right. Once I find an elegant solution for this I'll post it here. Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your date format as following:

```
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
SimpleDateFormat DtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YY");
Date date=cell.getDateCellValue();
System.out.println(DtFormat.format(date).toString());
```

This will print the value as 21.01.13.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for the hint which is part of the solution. I have to deal with a number of excel sheets with messed up formatting. Because of that, I don't know if I have a valid Date in the cell or not. If I am evaluating all cells in the sheets as Dates, just because getCellType() tells me it is a date, I will end up parsing wrong. All I know is that if the client opens up the sheet in excel, the Date is gonna be displayed like `01.12.12` (no matter if this cell is formatted properly as a date or not). Is there a way of getting the Excel-Equivalent-String of a cell's content?

Comment: Not sure but try `cell.toString();`

Comment: Thank's a lot, unfortunately in this case the `cell.toString()` acts exactly like `HSSFDataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)`

Comment: Do you maybe know how to get the String that represents the format (e.g. `"dd.MM.YY"`) out of the cell? Something like `String formatString=cell.getFormat();` for feeding it into `SimpleDateFormat(formatString);`